# How do I remove lines from every file that has a matching text?

Tags: linux, unix, ubuntu, grep

```
$ grep "console.log" * -R
account/db.js:        console.log(err);
account/db.js:        console.log(info);
account/db.js:                console.log(err);
account/db.js:                    console.log(err2);
account/controller.js:    console.log(covers);
account/controller.js:    console.log(req.api_user);
account/controller.js:    console.log(code);
account/controller.js:        console.log(user);
account/helper.js:                console.log(err);
messages/db.js:        console.log("Error " + err);
messages/helper.js:                console.log('No email notify.');
messages/helper.js:                console.log(msg_body);
messages/helper.js:                        console.log(message.sid);
messages/helper.js:                        console.log(message.dateCreated);
messages/helper.js:                        console.log(error);
products/controller.js:            console.log(product);
products/controller.js:                console.log(product);
products/helper.js:        console.log(data)
products/helper.js:    console.log('removing index....');
profile/db.js:                console.log(err);
profile/db.js:                console.log(info);
profile/db.js:                console.log(err);
profile/controller.js:                            console.log("sending phone confirmation text...");
profile/helper.js:            console.log(message.sid);
profile/helper.js:            console.log(message.dateCreated);
profile/helper.js:            console.log(error);
receiver/controller.js:    console.log(from);
receiver/controller.js:    console.log(body);
receiver/controller.js:        console.log(from_email);
receiver/controller.js:        console.log(to_id_gen);
receiver/controller.js:        console.log(finalbody);
receiver/controller.js:                            console.log(result);
reviews/db.js:        console.log(err);
reviews/db.js:        console.log(results);
reviews/controller.js:            console.log(review);
reviews/controller.js:    console.log(review_id);
search/controller.js:        console.log(JSON.stringify(data.hits.hits, null, 4));
```

As you can see, while I was writing my code, I was doing console.log everywhere.

Now, I want to remove all those lines.  I don't want to manually go into every file to remove them.  Instead, I want to do it via a command.

Similar to `grep "console.log" * -R`,  how can I do that same thing but remove those lines recursively? (look through every file all the way down the tree from my current directory)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try `find` for such things. try `find . -type f -exec sed -i '/console\.log/d' {} \;` but you might be interested in using `-i.bak` instead of `-i` which keeps a back up copy

Comment: `find -name \*.js -type f -exec sed -i.bak '/console\.log/d' {} +` might be more efficient.

Comment: Yes, at first it seemed so from the example provided. But then i noticed in anywhere in the grep, he has not used the file extension, or has not mentioned anywhere that only *js files are target. So I decided not to assume anything and skipped the -name option.

Answer (score 0):

Give this a shot.

```sh
sed -i.bak '/console.log/d' */*.js
```

The `-i` param edits files in place. The original file will have `.bak` appended to its name, so you can restore it if something goes wrong, or you change your mind.

This is not a properly recursive solution; you may need to modify the file name wildcard, or drive the command from a `find . -exec ...` wrapper to make it recursive.

Comment: This is not a recursive solution,

Comment: @abasu: for recursion, you can just use `zsh` and `sed -i '/console.log/d' **/*.js` glob pattern - cleaner than stuffing around with `find`....

Comment: So what do I type into my console?

Comment: All your matches seem to be one subdirectory deep; if so, the glob `*/*.js` should match them all, in any shell. Unless your directory tree is very deep or very complex, you can probably manage with a fairly simple set of wildcards, and a properly recursive solution is overkill.

Answer (score 0):

In Perl:

```
perl -i -n -e'print unless /console\.log/' $(find . -name '*.js')
```